How to restore a docker container redis dump file to Elasticache ( newly created )
Situation : I have a redis docker container running on local with some data of different kinds : Set, Hash, GeoHash.
Want to : Move the data from local redis container to a newly created Elasticache instance ( Cluster mode Disabled )
Tried :
Approach 1 :
Created a rdb file of local docker container data with :
sudo docker exec -it <containerId> bash redis-cli save.
This creates dump.rdb in /data
Copied rdb file on local from container
Copied rdb file to EC2 instance which is running in same VPC, Subnets as of Elasticache
Ran :
cat dump.rdb | redis-cli -h <cacheID>.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379 --pipe
This fails with :

All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply... 
ERR unknown command 'REDIS0012', with args beginning with: 'redis-ver7.4.1'
ERR unknown command 'redis-bits@ctime$used-mem', with args beginning with: Last reply received from server. 
errors: 2, replies: 2

Approach 2 :
While creating new Elasticache instance, there is an option to restore from backup ( below image ), this also fails with the local redis generated rdb file. Seems like this only works with Elasticache generated backups only. Don't know for sure, just a guess.

Question : How to take backup of a docker running redis instance & create a Elasticache instance with the same data ? Please help with this, Thanks.
